# How to use setPreferredSize(...) in sub class of JComponent?

Tags: java

I am trying to build my own JComponent that is not to fancy to start with. I can make an object and then add it to a JFrame or JPanel and it will add to the component list. I am not sure how to setPreferredSize().

**Question: How do I set the setPrefferedSize() and does it automatically set this specific size to all instance of the object when it is created**?

```
    **@Override
    public void setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize) {
        super.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
    }**
```

Class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class myComponent extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public myComponent() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,50));
        setToolTipText(new String("This is a custom buttion"));
    }

    **@Override
    public void setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize) {
        super.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
    }**

    @Override
    public void setToolTipText(String text) {
        super.setToolTipText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("I love pizza", 100, 100);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myComponent t = new myComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case you are not notified about this: I added an "EDIT" in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,50));
```

in the constructor, then ALL instances of your class will have this preferred size (as long as they use this constructor, of course).

BTW: Overriding a method and just calling the `super`-version of this method does not really make sense (as long as you are not increase the visibility from `protected` to `public` or so...). And the only method where you did NOT call the `super` version is that where you should actually do it: Usually, you override `paintComponent` as

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Your drawing here...
}
```

BTW2: Don't use `new String("foo")`. So the line

```
setToolTipText(new String("This is a custom buttion"));
```

should be

```
setToolTipText("This is a custom buttion");
```

EDIT: Maybe one should mention this as well: The intention behind the "preferred size" in Swing is slightly different. Usually, a class that extends JComponent has a an "intrinsic" preferred size. In your case, this could be (220, 220) because you want to paint a 200x200 rectangle with a 10 pixel margin. However, *users* of this component should be able to modify this preferred size by calling `setPreferredSize`, and passing in the desired size. But when they call `setPreferredSize(null)`, then the original, "intrinsic" preferred size should be used again. So in order to ensure proper handling of the preferred size, you could/should implement these methods like this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class myComponent extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public myComponent() {
        // setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,50)); Don't call this here!
        setToolTipText(new String("This is a custom buttion"));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (super.isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(220,220); // or (20,50), just as you want...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Lets say that I just wanted to set the setPrefferedSize () every time that I called a created a new instance of the object. Would I have to set the preferredSize() on every instance like MyObject.setPreffedSize(my size here);

Comment: What if I wanted to make this a JButton. I can only extend one class at a time. Would I have to create another class and then extend that class and so forth.

Comment: First comment: No. Every instance that you create automatically has the preferred size set in the constructor (or returns the appropriate size in its overridden `getPreferredSize` method, if you used the code from the EDIT). Second comment: It's rarely necessary to extend JButton. But of course, you *could* extend JButton (and set a preferred size in the constructor), or you could create a component that *contains* (only) a JButton and has the desired size... But I think that you should explain more clearly and in more detail what you want to achieve...